# Do two triangulations of a smooth manifold have a common subdivision?

Tags: smooth-manifolds, simplicial-complex, triangulation

The Hauptvermutung (ie. the question in the title) is known to be false for PL manifolds and topological manifolds, but I can't find a result for smooth manifolds (with boundary), though I recall reading it is true. If not, is something close to this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is false.

For example, there exists a triangulation of the smooth manifold $S^5$ which does not have a common subdivision (not even up to isotopy) with the standard triangulation of $S^5$ as the boundary of a $6$-simplex. This triangulation of $S^5$ was discovered by Edwards, who proved that if $M$ is certain homology $3$-sphere not homeomorphic to $S^3$ then the double suspension of $M$ is homeomorphic to $S^5$ (this was generalized by Cannon to all homology spheres not homeomorphic to spheres). If you then take any triangulation of $M$, and if you carry out the double suspension construction on the triangulation itself, the resulting triangulation of $S^5$ is the desired counterexample.

Now the thing one must be careful about here is that this triangulation of $S^5$ is *not smoothable*, i.e. it is not smooth and it cannot be isotoped to a smooth triangulation.

I am guessing that what you read was something like this: for any smooth manifold and for any two ***smooth*** triangulations of that manifold, those two triangulations have common subdivisions up to isotopy.

Comment: I see, thanks for your answer. I haven't been able to find a source for your last paragraph yet, but I assume the isotopy is necessary..

Comment: Well, sure, isotopy is necessary. Imagine two triangulations of $S^2$ and a choice of respective edges $e_1,e_2$ such that $e_1 \cap e_2$ is a countably infinite set.

Comment: I see, thanks. Would you know where I can find a statement of this result (about subdivisions up to isotopy)?

Comment: Hmm.... I'm not sure. The existence theorem for smooth triangulations (I believe it is a theorem of Whitney) seems easy to find in basic textbooks. It is definitely *false* to say that two smooth triangulations are smoothly isotopic; the best one can say is that there is a piecewise smooth isotopy. I'll poke around to see if I can find a reference, and perhaps someone else may weigh in.

Comment: Take a look at [these lecture notes of Lurie](https://www.math.ias.edu/~lurie/937notes/937Lecture5.pdf).